# Technique/class to clean invalid XML in AS3/Flex 4?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking for a way to load invalid (malformed) XML into an AS3 XML object. Do you know a class or a technique to do so? I have to load malformed HTML and parse it as XML.

This is a Flex project so I can use Flex specific classes if needed!

I thought of using the HTMLLoader since it accepts all kinds of malformed HTML and renders it properly but couldn't get anything to work...

Comment: OK, so I found a way to do that, still experimental and CPU intensive but looking good, though.

I'll post details and source when fully functionnal.
Note: Highly inspired by http://code.google.com/p/htmlscout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!
Yet to be improved but quite fast and handy!

Class is here: https://code.google.com/p/as3-bits/source/browse/trunk/bits/src/net/tw/util/air/HTMLFixer.as

Enjoy.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexes, how about nested tags?